# Hub with USB-A uplink and USB-C ports

Tags: usb, hub, usb-c

My PC only has USB-A ports. I want a hub which I can connect (so it needs USB-A connection) and which provides both USB-A and USB-C ports. I do not need any of the fancy optional features USB-C can provide like Thunderbolt, DisplayPort or high power output, just plain USB 3 will do.

The only devices I could find so far are of the *Docking Station* category with a very steep price tag. All the normal hubs I found with USB-C ports have a USB-C uplink connection as well.

The lack of such a device made me wonder, if there might be a technical (or legal) reason that such a device cannot exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technical reason: A USB-C device must be driven by a USB-C 'uplink' port in the PC. Since your PC does not have a USB-C port, no USB-C device can connect.

Therefore, I'd suggest adding a USB-C card such as a [$19 card](https://www.newegg.com/en-labs-model-pcieu3acs20/p/17Z-00FJ-00002) from NewEgg, or a [$25 card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FH6I0XK) from Amazon. Both connect to PCIe slots on your desktop motherboard, so please check that you have the necessary card slot available.

If your PC is a laptop, there's no solution for it, as the ExpressCard expansion card slot does not support USB-C.

Comment: Do you know why it needs a USB-C uplink? The USB 3.0 protocol should be independent of the plug used.

Comment: You asked for USB-C output, not USB 3.0. USB 3.0 is available on many Type A connectors. Note: Found a less spendy USB-C card for you, revised the answer to include its link.

Comment: I asked for USB3 over USB-C

Comment: No device will have a USB-C output if it doesn't have a USB-C input. That would guarantee a huge return rate from buyers who would expect USB-C ports to have full function.

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the use of the checkmark  (✅) below the arrowheads.